# Calling external REST API from bot

Tags: node.js, rest, botframework

I am trying to call a rest API by taking an argument as input parameter from user and then getting some sample information from a rest based web service.Can anyone help ?

Comment: "Can anyone help ?" > What have you tried so far?

Comment: Bot framework can be created in multiple languages.   Each language will have there own way to create a http message.    Rather than thinking of how a bot can call a rest API.   think in terms of how to i call an API in node, or how do I call an API in c#.    lots of info about that with a google search or even SO search

Comment: A bot built with bot framework is just a web API.  You can make a call to any rest API as you would with any other web api project.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
bot.dialog('postApiCallDialog', [
  (session) => {builder.Prompts.text(session, "First text input from the user")},
  (session, results) => {
    session.dialogData.firstInput = results.response
    builder.Prompts.number(session, "Second is the number input from the user")
  },
  (session, results) => {
    session.dialogData.secondInput = results.response
    // make the api call here with the inputs received from the user
    // below example is for a post call
      request.post('apiEndpoint', {
        'auth': {
            'user': 'abc',
            'pass': 'xyz',
            'sendImmediately': false
          }, 
          'json': {
            input1: session.dialogData.firstInput, 
            input2: session.dialogData.secondInput
          }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                // do stuff with data
                // use session.send / session.endDialog
              })        
  }
]).triggerAction({matches: 'postApiCall' })
```

If you need to make put call:

```
request.put('apiEndpoint', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'abc',
    'pass': 'xyz',
    'sendImmediately': false
 }, 'json': {field1: session.dialogData.firstInput, field2: "zzz"} // change the value of field1 to the first input received from the user
}, function (error, response, body) {
    // do stuff
})
```

for get

```
request.get(`apiEndpoint${session.dialogData.firstInput}`, { // some situation where your url is dependent on the input received from user
  'auth': {
    'user': 'abc',
    'pass': 'xyz',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    // do stuff
})
```

Authorizations in all the above api calls may vary depending on your case. You may check the documentation of nodejs request library for the same.